# Alphanumeric validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I can't understand why this alphanumeric check/validation doesn't work. I've cut the other switch options (that all work) 'cause the only check which doesn't work is the `else if (!(pswRegex.test(inputValue)))`. I'm not a jQuery/Javascript expert, so am I missing something?

The regex check should allow a password **only** if it's composed by letters (capital or non capital) and numbers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.req').on('input', function() {
        var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        var valueLenght = $(this).val().length;

        switch (inputID) {
            case "psw":
            var pswRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            if (valueLenght < 8) {
                $('#subButton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#err' + inputID).show().text("Password must be 8 carachters minimum");
            }
            else if (!(pswRegex.test(inputValue))) { 
                $('#subButton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#err' + inputID).show().text("Password must be alphanumeric");
            }
            else {
                $('#subButton').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#err' + inputID).hide();
            }
        break;
        }
  });

});
```

**[EDIT]**: what I wanted to achieve was displaying an error if the `inputValue` string contained **only** letters or **only** numbers: the user has to provide an alphanumeric password. Thanks to *Aioros* and *Peeyush Kushwaha* I understood that I can't achieve this with only a regex (at least with my actual knowledge about regular expressions), so I changed my `else if` condition with this one:

```
else if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(inputValue) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(inputValue)) { 
                $('#subButton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#err' + inputID).show().text("Password must be composed by both letters and numbers");
            }
```

**[EDIT 2]**: another clean and elegant solution is the one provided by *PanterA*. With only one `if` condition you can display (only) ***one*** error statement to the user saying that the password must be at least 8 carachters long and composed by, at least: one capital letter, one lower case letter and one number.

```
var pswRegex = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/;
if (!pswRegex.test(inputValue)) {
    $('#subButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#err' + inputID).show().text("Password must be at least 8 carachters long and composed by, at least, one capital letter, one lower case letter and one number");
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7890gLj/). What doesn't work for you exactly? What's the input?

Comment: @Aioros Maybe I'm using the regex `test()` in the wrong way, but let's suppose that `var inputValue = "asdwerasd";` -> this should return `false` from this check `(!(pswRegex.test(inputValue)))` and, in your file, print in the console.log `regex`, right? The problem is that it skipps the check as if it's always `true` displaying `ok` in your example and the `else` statement in mine

Comment: @brigo It shouldn't return false,  `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` means "either character or digit"

Comment: Well yes, it will say "ok" for the input "asdwerasd". Should it not?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha I was suspecting the error was a wrong understanding of regular expressions. I thought `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` was standing for "in the `var inputValue` there must be a string composed by, **at least**: one capital letter, one lower case letter and one number"

Comment: @brigo You should update your question with this new info so someone can help you figure out a regex for what you want (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex may help you:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).*$/
```

The positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`?=`) matches anything inside its parenthesis without being part of the result. Here we want the regex to find the minimal occurence of anything (`.*?`) followed by the caracters we want to enforce (Uppercase letters for example).

So this regex will check:

- At least one upper case letter: `(?=.*?[A-Z])`
- At least one lower case letter: `(?=.*?[a-z])`
- At least one digit: `(?=.*?[0-9])`

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/q7do1woL/

Also, If you want to validate the length of the string with regex, you can add a quantifier with a minimal value:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's cool mate! I've never went so deep into regular expressions 'cause they always scared me a bit, but this is the cleanest working solution for my problem! Thanks, I'm gonna study more about regex